# Copy row number of active cell to clipboard (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row

I want to create a macro that takes the row number of the active cell and copies it to the clipboard.

When I execute the following code I get 'compile error: invalid qualifier'.

I have forgotten most of my VBA but surely something this simple should work? Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

```
Sub macro3()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = ActiveCell.row
    x.Copy
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Using the solution below, I changed it to the following (which works):

After first adding a reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library under Tools > References in the VBE:

```
Sub macro3()
    Dim x As DataObject
    Set x = New DataObject
    x.settext ActiveCell.row
    x.putinclipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: An `Integer` (which btw use `Long` instead) doesn't have a `Copy` method.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/Clipboard_VBA). Btw, can I ask you why you would want this number in your clipboard?

Comment: Have a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738330/office-2013-excel-putinclipboard-is-different

Comment: I want to copy the number to the clipboard so that I can use it in a formula to import that row's data to a new table.

Answer (score 2):

One option, using a `DataObject` - add a reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` under *Tools* > *References* in the VBE.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x As DataObject
    Set x = New DataObject

    x.SetText ActiveCell.Row 'Or CStr(ActiveCell.Row) to make the type conversion explicit
    x.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work on Windows 10 since PutInClipboard is no longer supported.

Comment: @Netloh Works for me on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Weird. I haven't been able to use that method since upgrading. Need to make use of a Windows API instead. Like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738330/office-2013-excel-putinclipboard-is-different

Comment: Works in Windows 10 Pro as well. But you either need to add a UserForm or browse for FM20.dll in order to add the `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library`.

Comment: Thank you, using the DataObject variable worked for me (on Windows 10). I tried using Long variable, without success.

Comment: Because `DataObject` works with text (`String`). Not sure why you need a `Long` here anyway. Maybe edit your question with the revised code you're trying?

Comment: Done. Does that mean that the row number is text?

Comment: No. The row number is a long. It's just that `DataObject` works with text. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dataobject-object) some more reading.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336423/12418842). Since late binding is used, you do not need to add a reference.

Your code would look something like (the private sub is copied from the answer that I linked to above):

```
Sub RowNumberToClipboard()
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ActiveCell.Row

    Call CopyText (CStr(lRow))
End Sub


Private Sub CopyText(Text As String)
    'VBA Macro using late binding to copy text to clipboard.
    'By Justin Kay, 8/15/2014
    Dim MSForms_DataObject As Object
    Set MSForms_DataObject = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    MSForms_DataObject.SetText Text
    MSForms_DataObject.PutInClipboard
    Set MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @BigBen that makes sense. I tested the code and it works (even without converting the long to a string), but of course I agree that adding the `CStr()` is a better solution.

Comment: You should get a `ByRef argument Type Mismatch` error without the `CStr`. I'm not sure how you got your original code to work without the `CStr`.

Comment: @BigBen I don't want to argue about it since I definitely agree with you. But I tested the code without `CStr()` and it throws no error.

Comment: Would also work if you dropped the `As String` (though that's a bad idea too).