# how copy text from vba to windows clipbaord

Tags: vba, clipboard

I have an ms access vba code from which i wish to copy some text value to the Windows clipboard so that I can paste it elsewhere (Word/Excel/Notepad/etc).

I have been searching for this in SO but everything seems over-complicated.
Should it not be something simple like

clipboard.SetText textValue

?

EDIT

I tried following the hint by BrianMStafford but don't succeed. Perhaps the reason is that my object is a node in a tree.
When I do

> MsgBox Me.NodeKey.Value

it all works fine - I see the node path in the message box.

[image]

But when I do

> Me.NodeKey.SetFocus
> DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

I don't get the node path in the clipboard

So how can I copy the node path value into the Windows clipboard?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copy-getfromclipboard-gettext-methods-dataobject-object-example)?

Comment: @BrianMStafford This more sounds as get from clipboard.  I want to put something on the Windows clipboard.

Comment: That page shows how to read and write to the clipboard.  Specifically, use the .Copy method of the TextBox.

Comment: @BrianMStafford This is so incomprehensible.
I may be old school but I expect something like
Dim x as textbox
x = object.value
x.copy

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/21314039/16578424 - yes, there are some lines of code - but then you can use it straightforward.

Comment: One of the reasons the Clipboard API is not super convenient to use is that the clipboards target audience is not programmers, but users. There are numerous other methods of inter-process data transfer available, so using the clipboard is a bit kludgy,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as you say, however Access for some reason doesn't have the same "options" as excel. You have to add it manually or use Cristian Buse's answer which is pretty much the same, he is skipping adding the reference. So here is the way to manually add the reference to use `.SetText` in Access.

Access does not have the MS Forms listed on the Reference table like Excel (dont ask me why), but you can Browse to the file location and add it manually:

[image]

After you add this manually you can use the .SetText anywhere as long as you also declare the object of course.

```
Sub testCopy()
    Dim clipOb As MSForms.DataObject
    Set clipOb = New MSForms.DataObject
    clipOb.SetText Format(Now(), "m/d/yyyy")
    clipOb.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Now you can paste it anywhere. Just replace `Format(Now(), "m/d/yyyy")` with your `Me.NodeKey.Value`. If your Value is empty/blank it will give you an error, so just do a check before using `.SetText` to make sure you have a value to set.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo for this valuable hint. One thing though: I get an error when using this code: incorrect use of "New".

Comment: I tried modifying a little and found that the following works:
    > Dim clipOb As New MSForms.DataObject
    > clipOb.SetText Me.NodeKey.Value
    > clipOb.PutInClipboard

Comment: Incorrect use of New can be because of different Office versions/patches, glad you found a work around. I only tested the code on Access/Office 365 Version 2206 and it worked without any additions.

Comment: Note for future readers: the 'incorrect use of New' error resulted when not using the MSForms. prefix (now added in the answer).  I am using a Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2021 version.

Answer (score 5):

```
Public Sub WriteToClipboard(ByVal text As String)
    CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "text", text
End Sub
```

Example usage:

```
WriteToClipboard "test"
```

**Edit #1**

The above seems to work in Excel just fine. I only managed to make it work in Access for a specific computer. Once tested on another computer I got an error 70 (access denied).

The below only works in Excel if Windows Explorer is closed. However, it seems to work fine in Access regardless if Explorer is open/closed:

```
Public Sub WriteToClipboard(ByVal text As String)
    With CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}") 'MsForms.DataObject
        .SetText text
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: well this is no good - it closes Ms Access and does not result in clipboard having the required path

Comment: @Maestro13 Please see edit#1

Comment: If I understand correctly, this way of coding is called 'late binding'. Nice, but I prefer the early binding solution that RicardoA posted, even though that requires adding FM20.dll

Comment: Works great in Excel. Short and Sweet piece of code. Also I prefer LATE binding due to portability of the code (without having to fiddle with the GUI). Thank you @CristianBuse.

Comment: Works fine. Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20200) 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows API to Set Clipboard Data.

Here's the documentation page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/send-information-to-the-clipboard

Here's the code required with 2 example of how to use.
After running sub to save data to clipboard, just paste it anywhere.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Long, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long

Public Sub SetClipboard(sUniText As String)

    Dim iStrPtr As Long
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim iLock As Long
    
    Const GMEM_MOVEABLE As Long = &H2
    Const GMEM_ZEROINIT As Long = &H40
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = &HD
    
    OpenClipboard 0&
    EmptyClipboard
    
    iLen = LenB(sUniText) + 2&
    iStrPtr = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT, iLen)
    iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
    lstrcpy iLock, StrPtr(sUniText)
    GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
    SetClipboardData CF_UNICODETEXT, iStrPtr
    CloseClipboard
    
End Sub

Sub Example_SetClipboardData_1()

    SetClipboard "Hello World"
    
End Sub

Sub Example_SetClipboardData_2()
    
    Dim TextVar As String
    
    TextVar = "Hello again, World"
    SetClipboard TextVar
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why does it need to be so complex? Surely there is a simpler solution available?

Comment: You can review what each of the windows API functions do on the windows documentation here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard     As @Ike Mentioned, there is a shorter way, it just requires creating a textbox. Therefore, I view this method as superior.

Comment: Just stick it in it's own module, and you can call it super easily like `SetClipboard "Hello World"`, or `SetClipboard VariableThree`, or `SetClipboard "Lets all go to Stack Overflow"`

Answer (score 0):

When googling the object code that Cristian posted, I found a good page listing the possibilities, both early and late binding. Hence this page combines the answers by Christian Buse and Ricardo A.

See

https://desmondoshiwambo.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/how-to-copy-and-paste-text-tofrom-clipboard-using-vba-microsoft-access/