# Is it possible with VBA - EXCEL to control the office clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I have developed a project, and I need to secure certain user actions (copy/cut/paste) and to keep the cut/copy history - The Excel clipboard is insufficient, and in certain cases, the Executing vba code empties the contents of the clipboard. It seems appropriate to me to use the OFFICE clipboard, and in particular to replace the Excel clipboard in the CUT / PASTE actions with a code that replaces the ctrl X and ctrl V of Excel. For this I would like - 1- Copy ranges or objects in the OFFICE clipboard, then for the substitution of CTRL x, delete the range or the object in Excel, and in the CTRL V which follows, recover the second item from the OFFICE clipboard. I've been looking for several days, but NADA. It may be possible to use EXEL scripts, but I am not looking into this functionality. Before spending too much time on it, I would like to know if any of you know Excel scripts and tell me if it seems possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code and describe what it should do.

Comment: I thought there was only one "Clipboard" - the Windows Clipboard. Maybe I am wrong as [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-the-office-clipboard-028903c7-66ea-4eb0-b0a1-bacdb952e3a1) post suggests.

Comment: VBA Code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72806674/how-copy-text-from-vba-to-windows-clipbaord/72857101#comment134719963_72857101) is how to copy text from VBA to the Clipboard.

Comment: Here is another way - ` CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "text", sSomeData`

Comment: They are different apparently according to this post  ...  https://brainly.in/question/1505088#

Comment: Thank you all for your interest in this question, but I don't want to copy text to the office clipboard, but an Excel object, and on this side it's fine, the Selection.copy instruction sends the selection (range, graph , image, etc.) in the office clipboard. The problem is to retrieve the content, after running the code. or if for example I wanted to retrieve object 3 (from top to bottom) which appears in the clipboard panel and I found nothing. Even to recover the last stuck object. –

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful clipboard functions for excel:

```
Sub copy(ByVal text As String)
    Dim objClipboard As Object
    Set objClipboard = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    objClipboard.SetText text
    objClipboard.PutInClipboard
    Set objClipboard = Nothing
End Sub

Function paste() As String
    Dim objClipboard As Object
    Set objClipboard = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    objClipboard.getFromClipboard
    paste = objClipboard.getText
    Set objClipboard = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416662/text-to-clipboard-in-vba-windows-10-issue

Comment: My problem is that I cannot recover the objects copied by VBA. If I do selection.copy, the object is indeed copied to the office clipboard, but if I don't immediately retrieve the contents of the office clipboard and run some vba code between, Activesheet.paste throws an error 1004, selection paste an error 438

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from the Macro Recorder the following code pastes all six items from the Office Clipboard.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Range("G28").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
    ActiveSheet.paste
    ActiveSheet.paste
    ActiveSheet.paste
    ActiveSheet.paste
    ActiveSheet.paste
    ActiveSheet.paste
    Range("M28").Select
End Sub
```

The difference appears to be that the Office Clipboard saves 24 items that have been copied whereas the Windows Clipboard only saves one.

I generated this by first placing six items in the Office Clipboard and then using the Macro Recorder to track the VBA used for the following command ...

Excel > Home > Clipboard > <kbd>Paste All</kbd>

Comment: Yes, it works if you copy to the clipboard, then immediately after, paste. But if you run some code in the meantime, nothing works. The problem is therefore to recover the contents of the OFFICE clipboard. That of Excel only retains the last action and is also emptied by the execution of code after the copy (at least under certain conditions) resorting to the contents of the office clipboard is then necessary, but obviously Microsoft has not anticipated this scenario and is content with his archaic excel clipboard

Comment: @phmauber on my computer, using Excel365, several actions are retained as I tried to illustrate above. I don't think there is an *Office* clipboard as such, there needs to be an Office product running, like Excel, to retain the copy actions. As soon as you come out of Excel the list of copy actions is lost, I have watched it happen.

Comment: @phmauber watch this space as I may be able to improve the manageability of the functionality that is there - but I am not full time on this and therefore very slow to respond with something like this. 8-)

Comment: @phmauber I have worked with the Office Clipboard open for a couple of days now and as far as I have seen *in certain cases, executing vba code empties the contents of the clipboard* is not happening, the opposite is true. However, exiting all Office products empties the Office Clipboard except when there is an object in the Windows Clipboard and this remains.

Comment: There is another exception ... in some circumstances for example copying an Excel .xlsm file I got the error message *Item not collected format not supported by the Office Clipboard* which then begs the question - What objects are and what are not collected by the Office Clipboard?

Comment: Objects collected by ofice clipboard are. Range, shapes, listobjects, pivottables

Answer (score 0):

> For now, the only thing I could do is:
> make the office clipboard active reassign ctrl+c keys
> ctrl+v
> ctrl+x so that ctrl+c copies to the office clipboard. ctrl+x copy to the office clipboard, before sending the cut command (this keeps a
> copy of the cut object for ctrl+v, as I am still unable to select an
> object from the office clipboard to manipulate it, I display the
> clipboard panel, then I carry out several checks, (current selection
> empty, current selection part of a filtered range , then I send a few
> messages to the user). It is up to the user to click on the element of
> the office clipboard that they want to paste. It’s this last part that
> I would like to control, but is it possible and how?

```
    Option Explicit

'* Procédure pour gérer l'événement Ctrl+C
Sub HandleCtrlC(Optional shdw As Boolean)
Dim cBar As CommandBar

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Définir le CommandBar du presse-papier Office
Set cBar = Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard")
If cBar.Enabled = False Then
 cBar.Enabled = True
Exit Sub
End If

Selection.Copy

End Sub
'***************************************************************************************************************************************
'* Procédure pour gérer l'événement Ctrl+V
Sub HandleCtrlV(Optional shdw As Boolean)

Dim rng As Range
Dim cBar As CommandBar
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set cBar = Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard")

            Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
            '* Vérifie si la plage est filtrée
            If rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count Then
            '* Si la plage est filtrée, affiche un message d'erreur et quitte la procédure
                             MsgBox "La région courante de la cellule active est filtrée." & vbCr _
                    & "Copie de la plage impossible sans risque important de corrompre la base " & vbCr _
                    & "défiltrez la base avant de coller ", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "ATTENTION, Supprimez les filtres"
                   Exit Sub
 
            ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Attention, la plage de destination n'est pas vide, ... ", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "ATTENTION"
                End If
                cBar.Visible = True
                If MsgBox("Cliquez sur les données du presse papier que vous voulez colle   r" & vbCr _
                & "Si vous voulez préserver les données que vous allez écraser, " & vbCr _
                & "Selectionnez les et copier  les (CTRLC ou Copier) " & vbCr _
                & "elles seront mises à l'abris dans le Presse papier", vbOKOnly) = 6 Then
                     ' voir un user form nodal pour guider l'utilisateur
             
                
            'voir l'execution de la routine qui suit apres ctrl V
            met_cells_col_date_ddmmyy
            
            End If

fin:

Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
'***************************************************************************************************************************************
'* Procédure pour gérer l'événement Ctrl+X
Sub HandleCtrlX(Optional shdw As Boolean)
Dim cBar As CommandBar

Set cBar = Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard")
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Définir le CommandBar du presse-papier Office
Set cBar = Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard")
If cBar.Enabled = False Then
 cBar.Enabled = True
Exit Sub
End If
    Selection.Copy
'* Utilise la fonction Cut par défaut d'Excel si la sélection n'est pas une plage
    Selection.Cut

 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```