How to copy cells from excel to one long string
I tried to make some simple excel makro for copying id. nr. of our items to our company ERP system. I dont know how to copy data to one string, so ERP system can find all of items. My makro makes everything what I wanted, but it copy cells under.
Here is example what i want:
7042151,7042152,7042153,7042154,7042145,7042155,7025449,3012928,3006999,3002768,3002761,3002768,3010873,3008762,3001228,3002761,3760114

And here is example what i got from makro.
7042151,
7042152,
7042153,
7042154,
7042145,
7042155,
7025449,
3012928,
3006999,
3002768,
3002761,
3002768,
3010873,
3008762,
3001228,
3002761,
3760114

Here is my code:
Sub copytext()
    Dim txt As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Last_Col As Long
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Set rng = Application.Selection
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set txt = Application.ActiveSheet
    rng.Copy
    Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0))
      .Value = Evaluate(Replace("if(@<>"""",@&"","")", "@", .Address))
    End With
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select
    Range("A1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Range("A1"))
    Selection.Copy
End Sub

It should work like you highlight cells with data, click on makro, and makro make copy in right format to clipboard.
I tried this after Selection.Copy but it was same.

    Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim strText As String
    objData.GetFromClipboard
    strText = objData.GetText
    objData.SetText strText
    objData.PutInClipboard


Just use =TEXTJOIN

This code set the new workbook activesheet cell A1 to the generated value from the Application.Selection property, and paste it to the clipboard.
Sub copytext()
    Dim txt As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Last_Col As Long
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Set rng = Application.Selection
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    'Set txt = Application.ActiveSheet   not used
    Dim outtext As String
    For Each cel In rng
      If outtext = "" Then
      outtext = cel.Value
      Else
      outtext = outtext & "," & cel.Value
      End If
    Next cel
    
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1") = outtext
    'LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select
    Range("A1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Range("A1"))
    Selection.Copy
End Sub


If you are on Excel 365 you can use the TextJoin-function plus API-call to clipboard.
Sub copyToString(rg As Range)

Dim t As String
t = Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, rg)

ClipBoard_SetData t
End Sub

Call the sub like this: copyToString Selection
Regarding copying to the clipboard:
Put the code from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21314039/16578424) into a new module, e.g. mdlClipboard.
If you are on a 64bit Excel then you have to use an adapted code like this:
Option Explicit
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738330/office-2013-excel-putinclipboard-is-different

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr


Private Const GHND  As Long = &H42
Private Const CF_TEXT As Long = 1

Public Sub ClipBoard_SetData(MyString As String)
    Dim hGlobalMemory As LongPtr, lpGlobalMemory As LongPtr, hClipMemory As LongPtr
   Dim X As Long
   ' Allocate moveable global memory.
   '-------------------------------------------
   hGlobalMemory = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(MyString) + 1)

   ' Lock the block to get a far pointer
   ' to this memory.
   lpGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hGlobalMemory)

   ' Copy the string to this global memory.
   lpGlobalMemory = lstrcpy(lpGlobalMemory, MyString)

   ' Unlock the memory.
   If GlobalUnlock(hGlobalMemory) <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not unlock memory location. Copy aborted. "
      GoTo OutOfHere2
   End If

   ' Open the Clipboard to copy data to.
   If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not open the Clipboard. Copy aborted."
      Exit Sub
   End If

   ' Clear the Clipboard.
   X = EmptyClipboard()

   ' Copy the data to the Clipboard.
   hClipMemory = SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlobalMemory)

OutOfHere2:

   If CloseClipboard() = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not close Clipboard. P"
   End If

End Sub

